# Image in a div with links

Tags: html, css

Trying to include an image in a div that has site navigation (done with links and css). However I cant seem to get the organization correct between the divs and the image.

Fiddle link for visual explanation: https://jsfiddle.net/ve2f7o18/
(im trying to have the logo "raven" placed inside the black navagation bar to the left of "essays"

Tried creating another div to hold the image, tried placing the image outside the div.

```css
#buttonParent {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px 10px #888888;
  background-color: black;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#buttons {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

#logo {
  color: coral;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonParent">
  <div id="buttons">

    <img id="logo" src="img\raven.png" alt="logo" />

    <a class=esnav href=essays.html target="iMain"> Essays </a>
    <a class=esnav href=genres.html target="iMain"> Genres </a>
    <a class=esnav href=index.html target="iMain"> Index </a>
    <a class=esnav href=writers.html target="iMain"> Writers </a>
    <a class=esnav href=canon.html target="iMain"> Western Canon </a>
    <a class=esnav href=stories.html target="iMain"> Short Stories </a>



  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your logo seems to be on the left of the essays?  It is unclear what the problem is, please can you clarify

Comment: @Pete For whatever reason, the logo only shows up on the fiddle, and not in my actual code written in my IDE, and I dont know what the issue is, not even the alt text shows up on the web page in my browser.

Comment: If you inspect the element (or the essays link and then click on the image)  in your ide, does it have any additional styles?

Comment: @Pete I solved the problem by taking out the style line changing the image color to white and creating a new image with an actual white color in photoshop and changing the image I was using to the new one. Thanks.